# Stack Smashing Detected in GCC

Tags: c, linux

I'm new to C and I've found a peculiar output from gcc that I'm having a hard time getting to the bottom of. The error upon running the application is:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: /home/joshua/Research/cml/test terminated

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7a43428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
54  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

I've done some research on this, and it appears that this is many times caused by tying to put too large a value into an array, for example; I'm not doing anything like that.

Here is my sample code for reference:

```
 1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <string.h>
  3  
  4 struct student
  5 {
  6      int id;
  7      char name[10];
  8      float percentage;
  9 };   
 10  
 11 int main()
 12 {
 13      int i;
 14      struct student record[2];
 15      
 16      // 1st student's record
 17      record[0].id=1;
 18      strcpy(record[0].name, "Raju");
 19      record[0].percentage = 86.5;
 20      
 21      // 2nd student's record         
 22      record[1].id=2;
 23      strcpy(record[1].name, "Surendren");
 24      record[1].percentage = 90.5;
 25      
 26      // 3rd student's record
 27      record[2].id=3;
 28      strcpy(record[2].name, "Thiyagu");
 29      record[2].percentage = 81.5;
 30      
 31      for(i=0; i<3; i++)
 32      {
 33          printf("     Records of STUDENT : %d \n", i+1);
 34          printf(" Id is: %d \n", record[i].id);
 35          printf(" Name is: %s \n", record[i].name);
 36          printf(" Percentage is: %f\n\n",record[i].percentage);
 37      }   
 38      return 0;
 39 }
```

Comment: You're doing **exactly** that - arrays are zero-based in C.

Comment: Accessing `3rd` element in an array of size `2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `2` in

```
struct student record[2];
```

is not the top index, it is the number of elements. And as you seem to know indexes start at zero which means the valid indexes are `0` and `1` for the above array. Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't realize that number represented the total number of elements. Noob mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
struct student record[2];
```

You've got an array of size 2 and you're trying to store 3 elements in it. Array indices go from 0 to n-1. `record[2]` is an invalid index.

Comment: So, when record has a size of "record[2]", I find it interesting that there isn't an error thrown on the line where record[2] index is assigned some values. In fact, I used GDB to look into memory, and the values were assigned to memory in this last index. However, the error didn't occur until the return statement. Can anyone give insight into why this is?

Answer (score -1):

To keep a check on the integrity of the functions, next to the return statement Gcc adds protection variables (called canaries) which have known values.In your case when the uninitialized access is done on record[2] you have violated the stacks integrity and the canary values are overwritten which trigger the crash.

Comment: It is not guaranteed gcc adds extra data on the stack. It is more a matter of the ABI and platform in general.

Comment: @olaf I think I have explained the behavior the program and what could have gone wrong .